# Load rtf and pdf using UIWebview from local

Tags: ios, pdf, uiwebview, load, rtf

I knew this question is already asked here. But I am facing some issue which is not getting resolved.

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fileCacheDirPath = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:kATTACHMENTS_FOLDER];
    NSString *filePath = [fileCacheDirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:_fileItemDataModel.name];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath isDirectory:NO];
```

Error:

> url :
>   file:///Users/Sanoj/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/722-6542-4E14-9CC5-24F96EE305D9/data/Containers/Data/Application/B990D3-4311-B580-D2E00E75/Documents/AttachmentsFolder/Scrum_Methodology.pdf
>
> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out."
>   UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x60800084d950 {Error
>   Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "The request timed out."
>   UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=file:///Users/Sanoj/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/722CC1FA-6542-4E14-9CC5-24F96EE305D9/data/Containers/Data/Application/B992A9C0-A0D3-4311-B580-D2E0049CFE75/Documents/AttachmentsFolder/Scrum_Methodology.pdf,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=file:///Users/Sanoj/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/722CC1FA-6542-4E14-9CC5-24F96EE305D9/data/Containers/Data/Application/B992A9C0-A0D3-4311-B580-D2E0049CFE75/Documents/AttachmentsFolder/Scrum_Methodology.pdf,
>   _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}},
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=file:///Users/Sanoj/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/722CC1FA-6542-4E14-9CC5-24F96EE305D9/data/Containers/Data/Application/B992A9C0-A0D3-4311-B580-D2E0049CFE75/Documents/AttachmentsFolder/Scrum_Methodology.pdf,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=file:///Users/Sanoj/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/722CC1FA-6542-4E14-9CC5-24F96EE305D9/data/Containers/Data/Application/B992A9C0-A0D3-4311-B580-D2E0049CFE75/Documents/AttachmentsFolder/Scrum_Methodology.pdf,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}

Comment: There should be `NSURL.fileURL`  instead  of NSURL URLWithString may that help

Comment: I tried using as I mentioned in question itself, but no luck., It's called didstartdownload and didfail method of delegate.

Comment: Have you check that file exits at path or not ?, With  fileManager fileExistsAtPath

Comment: yes that is there, After printing path manually I am check with that url.

Comment: But you should check NSFileManager's  fileExistsAtPath Method and also observe  AttachmentsFolder.Scrum_Methodology.pdf is it correct  it is unlike AttachmentsFolder / Scrum_Methodology.pdf

Comment: I have done some correction in question, there was mistake so change that but now request time out is coming.

Comment: you should  load `URLRequest` instead of Loading URL directly

Comment: Yeah, I am doing that one, that is not mentioned in the question. I am creating NSURLRequest only.

Comment: Aside: I notice your posts are rather chatty for an experienced user. May I ask you to make them a bit more succinct in the future? I notice "if someone can help me", "Anyone can help me to understand this", "Any help?", "Please, let help me" (etc). This seems to be a mixture of unnecessary fluff and begging, which over the course of time will add up to a fair bit of volunteer editing time. Thank you, if you can reduce this somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

it worked with following code

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
           NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
           NSString *fileCacheDirPath = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:kATTACHMENTS_FOLDER];
           NSString *filePath = [fileCacheDirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:_fileItemDataModel.name];
           [self.webView loadData:_fileItemDataModel.data MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath]];
```

Please, check